# "Turn on the radio" or "put on the radio"?

Tags: word-choice

Are both of these correct?

> "Turn on the radio"
>
> "Put on the radio"

Comment: I've never heard "put on the radio". It doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Most English speaking people will not say the latter.

Comment: I agree that "put on the radio" sounds odd, but I've definitely heard, "put the radio on"

Answer (score 2):

We commonly *turn on* the television, radio, heater, lights, stove or anything else that requires a switch or knob to operate.

We do, however, *put on* the kettle, coffee, clothes, jewelry, things we wear, or manners/affectations (*put on airs*).

Comment: +1, although you could say "Put 104.7 on the radio".

Answer (score 0):

Both are used. "Put on the radio" is allowed, or at least is written, but "put the radio on" is more common, which may be why the comments to the OP say "put on the radio" sounds so foreign.

I am not smart enough to know how to insert the images but here are the ngrams on the matter.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put+the+radio+on%2Cturn+the+radio+on%2Cturn+on+the+radio%2Cput+on+the+radio&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cput%20the%20radio%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cturn%20the%20radio%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cturn%20on%20the%20radio%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cput%20on%20the%20radio%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Where do you live/what variety of English do you speak? Because in my experience, only non-native speakers would ever utter "put on the radio".

Comment: US English, Seattle. I would venture that I hear it more often as a command.

Comment: There are 36 800 000 Google hits for "put on the radio" here and now. Which does not surprise me at all. And 30,400,000 for "turn on the radio". Again, I'm not surprised. But the versions with the particle postposed score far less highly, which does surprise me. Probably, though as Unrelated says this [may be] more common [in the UK], Google isn't picking up speech pattern preferences.